# Laptop not going to Sleep with press of Power Button

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep

The power button of my laptop won't go into sleep-mode anymore after a single press of the power button.

The button physically works for all other cases, like booting, waking up from sleep, shutdown with a long-press.

In power settings "When I press the power button" is set to "Sleep". Changing it to for example Hibernate won't do anything either.

Laptop: ROG Zephyrus G14
OS: Win10

Comment: Reset your Power Settings to default. Update BIOS and the Power Driver. Restart, Set up power settings again and test.

Answer (score -1):

What fixed it in my case:

1. In Device Manager, go to "System devices" and find "ACPI Fixed Feature Button"
2. Uninstall it. Say no to restarting.
3. Start a PowerShell as Administrator and run `sfc /scannow`
4. When done, restart the laptop
5. Issue was fixed for me at this point, the power button was reactive again.

Comment: What is the purpose of `scf /scannow` (which by the way is the incorrect command)?  The correct command would be `sfc /scannow`.  System File Check (SFC).

Comment: Sorry about that, I corrected it.

I am not very knowledgeable on the topic. From what I understand it fixes some corrupted driver file(s). All I know is that it worked. I just posted it to maybe help someone else because i spent hours searching.

Comment: SFC would not fix corrupt drives.  It only scans system files, third-party device drivers, are not included in that scan.

Answer (score -1):

These steps worked for me:

1. In Device Manager, go to "System devices" and find "ACPI Fixed Feature Button"
2. Uninstall it. Say yes to restarting.
3. Issue was fixed after the restart.

This is Drycee's solution without the SFC step.

Comment: It is discouraged to answer old questions unless you have something substantial to add.  Duplicating an existing answer, but removing a surperflous step doesn't meet that standard.  If you can improve someone else's answer, you are encouraged to edit it directly.